# react useEffect not cleaning up event listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, event-listener, use-effect

I tried following 2 methods to remove event handler but both don't seem to work

Solution 1:

```js
  const keyBindSearch = useCallback(e => {
    if ((e.metaKey && e.key === 'f') || (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'f')) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('CTRL F')
    }
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch)

    return () => {
      console.log('REMOVE')
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch)
    }
  }, [])
```

Solution 2:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const keyBindSearch = e => {
      if ((e.metaKey && e.key === 'f') || (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'f')) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('CTRL F')
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch)

    return () => {
      console.log('REMOVE')
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch)
    }
  }, [])
```

I see `REMOVE` in console so clean-up function from `useEffect` is definitely firing but event listener is not deleted and still logs `CTRL F` even after clean-up function is called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please pass dependency for useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Solution 2 at least. Remember, the eventListener will be removed when the element is removed and not rendered again (otherwise the useEffect will bind the eventListener again). See my sample, when you remove the component, there is no CTRL F logged: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chatelet-e9qpv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh didn't know that useEffect will bind the eventListener again if it's not removed. This should've been the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document, try window.
Change this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch) //change document to window
```

to:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch)
```

Do this for removing as well. eg:

```
window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyBindSearch);
```

Might work for you. cheers

Comment: tried with `window` originally but didn't work so changed to `document` to see if it works